# How long does it take to do a yodlee implementation?

Tags: yodlee

I'm a non-technical (well, non-software. hardware background) founder who has hired a pretty good developer that has built a site with backend on Rails and frontend with CSS/HTML pretty capably. our next step is to develop a Yodlee integration, and we both want to know how long it takes to do this. He has an estimate which I think is reasonable, but would like feedback from the community without biasing the responses.

Also, if anybody has done an implementation before, I would really appreciate your perspective and help!

Answer (score 35):

I have implemented a complex Yodlee integration for a LA based start-up over the last two years. They built a social game and money management platform on top of it. The short answer is that it's tough and dirty work.

The technical aspect of getting your application to communicate to the Yodlee API is not at all the hard part (its pretty much a standard web service). Following are some aspects highlighting the difficulty:

- The most difficult part is dealing with the unknowns and the variability in the client data.
- There is effectively no documentation for the API
- There are several way to do each operation that will return different data

Ive been designing and building systems for 15 years and have gotten pretty good at estimating projects. We were way off with Yodlee; in fact we are still dealing with issues. 
In order to understand why its so tough, you really need to understand what Yodlee is.. it is an aggregator of 10,000 different systems. Now these other systems might be big professional systems like Bank of America, Chase, ... but they are often small little banks (Bob's Bank in Omaha).

When Yodlee communicates with the big companies (they are called content services) there is most always an api that actually returns good data. But with the little ones, they are doing screen scraping. You can imagine that breaks all the time. They have an entire team in India which is just focused on that.

The other issue is about modelling the data; each of the content services at its source has modeled the data differentley (different names, different elements, different relationships,...) but Yodlee but combine all 10,000 models into one view. What this leaves you with is a very bloated model, where you can never know or count on getting a certain data element.

To give you an idea... there are extra fields about a credit account (apr, credit amount, last payment, ...) beyond the standard base'class fields (balance, ...). While this sounds great that you have this data, in practice the number of content services that provide these extra data elements is so low that you cant really depend on them. I'd say that the fidelity of those data elements is very low. All you can really count on is the base elements (account name, type, balance) and (transaction date, description and type).

Speaking of transactions... their transaction categorization system is not that good. They have clearly taken a breadth first approach to this, rather than focus on accuracy. We built an entire system for transaction categorization which is far more effective.

A couple other things: The DAG account test system is useless; it does not operate the same way real accounts do. You will be far better off opening 5-10 accounts at different content services and giving your developers the username/passwords for these for testing. The MFA (multifactor auth) system for account security has been an endless headache. This isnt Yodlee's fault, its the nature of the game. The banks are doing more and more crazy things that add security layers. Yodlee has the MFA system in place to compensate for this. At any given time about 20% of our accounts are in error for some reason. We have built an entire component just to manage this.

So what does this all mean? Double your estimate, get ready to get dirty. I dont want to put Yodlee down at all (except for the lack of documentation); they really are solving a hard problem. There really arent any other better options.

Comment: Agreed. With the DAG you can't actually create accounts to actual banks. You can 'spoof' login and transactions, but you won't be testing an actual flow with a real bank.

Comment: Great, just started an integration to them - Based on how old this post is I was expecting the implementation to be better by now, but many of the points you make are still valid. And the example test app they provide, which apparently can be used as a base to build your implementation is a joke.

Answer (score 5):

I run the team responsible for sales and support of the Yodlee APIs so the response may be a little biased.

I have seen clients get up and running in anywhere from 10 days to 3 months to 6 months. The time to implement depends on the number of fields in the data model you are using and how you are going to use the data or manipulate it before presenting it to your users.

While the most prevalent data fields such as account balance or transaction amount will always be available, Craig is right, as you get into the broader data model you will have to code for exceptions when the data is not there. Yodlee does provide documentation on how often the fields will be available to help with this process. But if you are only going to be using basic account and transactional information, you will not have to worry about these complexities and it will speed implementation.

How you use the data once you receive it from Yodlee will also play a big part in the time it takes to get integrated. If you are deriving additional data from the transaction descriptions or are doing something with categorization then there is more complexity and it will require more time. If you are using many of the fields as-is, then this will be easier.

The other item that Craig mentioned is the extra security questions (Multi-factor Authentication). While that section of the API does add some work, we have added documentation around this to make integration easier. Also, with any development issues that come up we give clients access to a developer forum that is monitored by our Technical Consulting team.